# To Display Form in Parentpanel on clicking a button control inside subpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have four Forms. Form1,Form2,Form3,Form4.
when i click a button inside form1.panel1 , form2 gets displayed in form1.panel1.   Form2 also has a panel and button. 
on clicking button control in form2, form3 appears in the small panel contained in form2. i acheived all the above action by  the following code on button click,\

```
        panel1.Controls.Clear(); 
        form2 f2 = new form2();
        f2.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
        f2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        panel1.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - panel1.Size.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - panel1.Size.Height / 2);
        panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f2.Show();
```

What i want to achieve is when i click form3(appeared in  subpanel of form2),form4 should appear in parentpanel(say form1.panel1)

i used the code below , but the form is not displayed.

```
        Form4 f4 = new Form4();

        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f4.TopLevel = false;
        f1.panel1.Controls.Clear();
        f1.panel1.Controls.Add(f4);
        f4.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        f1.panel1.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - f1.panel1.Size.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - f1.panel1.Size.Height / 2);
        f1.panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        f1.panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Hide();

        f4.Show();
```

how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing now is that you're creating a new instance of `form1` in `form3`. What you have to do is to pass the `f1` (using `this` in `form1`) as argument from `form1` to `form2` to `form3`, this way you have access to your original `form1` in every other form.

There may be a better solution, but this is the one I can think of now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you solved it yet? Please accept this answer if it helped.